# Take the image printed with plt.imshow as a variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, imshow

I'm using a custom library to transform a 1D signal to a 2D representation. The output it's printed through plt.imshow(), used by a function inside of the library. I have the result but i don't want to save the picture locally. There is a way to get as a PIL image what is being used by plt.imshow?

EDIT: The answer is yes, as @Davide_sd is pointing out ax.images[idx].get_array() can be used to retrieve the data

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ax.images[idx].get_array()` to retrieve the data, after which you can use it on PIL. `ax` is the axes where the image has been plotted. `idx` is the index of the image you are interested: if you have plotted a single image, then `idx=0`.